# Expression-based connection string doesn't render report

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm trying to get reports working in an ASP.NET MVC application. SSRS is installed on the SQL2012 box separate from the IIS box. I'm using the ReportViewer control in a WebForms page to render reports. My dev environment is a server with both IIS and SQL Server/SSRS, with both development and QA databases.

I've set up reports to use a parameter for the connection string. The value is coming from the web.config. Everything works fine on development and QA, but when we deploy to production, the ReportViewer only gives the dreaded blank page. I know reports are working on production because I created a sample report that doesn't use a data source, and put the connection string parameter as a textbox, and everything renders as expected, displaying the correct connection string.

I've been all over the web without success. Because the sample report renders and displays the dynamic connection string, I'm suspicious the problem might be in the connection string itself. I've tried

`Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;User Id=sqluser;Password=sqlpass;`

along with every variation of the server name (IP address, localhost, etc.). The data source in the reports is set to use no credentials so they're passed in via the connection string. The reports work fine from development and QA if I pass the live server as the parameter.

What am I missing? How do I use a dynamic data source on a report that's rendered on a box separate from the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this helps but I have done something similar and had an issue with the data source when I deployed the report to the SSRS report server.

I have an Environment parameter to determine which server to use:

```
=IIF(Parameters!Environment.Value = "PRD", "Data Source = xSQLPRD01\PRDMAIN; Initial Catalog = PlanData_Custom", 
    IIF(Parameters!Environment.Value = "UAT", "Data Source = xSQLUAT01\UATMAIN; Initial Catalog = PlanData_Custom", 
    IIF(Parameters!Environment.Value = "UPG", "Data Source = xSQLUPG01\UPGMAIN ; Initial Catalog = PlanData_Custom",
    "Data Source = xSQLTST01\TSTMAIN;Initial Catalog = PlanData_Custom")))
& ";User ID=user;Password=Password1"
```

It works in BIDS but when I deploy it, I get an error that the datasource is not valid.

I figured out that I needed to add credentials to the datasource. It had defaulted to **Credentials Are Not Required**.

If you have a similar Data Source page, try adding your credentials.

[image]

Comment: Success! I banged my head against the wall for three days trying to make this work. Thank you so much.